# How to parse .css files as PostCSS in vscode?

Tags: css, sass, visual-studio-code, postcss

I'm using PostCSS in a project, and the extension of the CSS files is `.css` so when I open one, it will indicate bunch of errors (due to the syntax of PostCSS).

I have tried installing `stylelint`, `PostCSS syntax` extensions etc... but nothing worked.

If I change the extension to `.scss`, it works fine but I'm not using SASS.

What should I do to remove the parsing errors in the `.css` files?

**Update:**

File example with PostCSS extension, as you can see bad coloration and no errors highlighted

[image]

If I change the file extension to .scss :

[image]

**Update 2 :**

I tried with this plugin, and it works like a charm : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mhmadhamster.postcss-language

Answer (score 17):

Try this extension for VSCode: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ricard.PostCSS

Add the following line in your user settings and you should be good to go:

```
"files.associations": {
   "*.css": "postcss"
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works. And for those of you are wondering why your `.css` file keeps getting recognized as PostCSS by default, just change to `"*.css": "css"`

Answer (score 5):

Just a tiny tweak to the @Jiib answer...

```
"files.associations": {
   "*.css": "postcss"
}
```

add that to the settings.json file...

Then add this plugin... [Language-PostCss](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cpylua.language-postcss)

This plugin wants you to make the css files .pcss or .postcss however adding the file association automatically does that for us.

Good times...

Answer (score 0):

v1.23 might have fixed your "apparent" errors, adding support for newer properties as might be used in postCSS.  [v1.23 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_improved-css-support-for-new-properties)