# Errors on CSS files because of the nesting rules

Tags: css, tailwind-css, postcss

I'm building a project which is using tailwindcss + postcss. I also have tailwindcss/nesting plugin, and that's where the issue comes in.

I am getting VSCode errors on my CSS files because of the nesting rules. This is fixed when I change my **.css** file to **.pcss**, is this normal? Should I change all the files to **.pcss** to prevent the nesting VSCode errors or is there a better alternative?

Comment: It would help if you added the error message and some sample code.
Without anything concrete it is impossible to provide a helpful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to parse .css files as PostCSS in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981905/how-to-parse-css-files-as-postcss-in-vscode)

This StackOverflow post answered my question ^

Change this in the User Settings (JSON) VSCode

```
"files.associations": {
   "*.css": "postcss"
}
```